# Using mvrnorm from MASS package

Tags: r

I need to generate a random sample with a multivariate normal distribution using `seed(12346)` with 100 columns and 5000 rows.

So far I have got this:

```r
set.seed(12346) 
Preg1 <- data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n=5000,mu=c(0,0,0),Sigma = diag(3)))
```

The above gives me three columns, how can I get 100?

I cannot figure out how to get the vector of mu with 100 zeros without typing them in and the Sigma would then be `Sigma = diag(100)`

Comment: Maybe `mu = rep(0, 100)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mu = rep(0, 100)`. The `rep` function is used to repeat values.

```
set.seed(12346)
ncol = 100
Preg1<-data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 5000, mu = rep(0, ncol), Sigma = diag(ncol)))

dim(Preg1)
# [1] 5000  100
```

The `rep` function is quite useful, it can be used in various ways that aren't applicable here but are good to know about:

```
rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 3)
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C"

rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 1:3)
# [1] "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"

rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3)
# [1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

---

In this particular case, because your `Sigma` is an identity matrix, each column is actually independent. So it would be equivalent to generate each column (or even each draw) independently, which we could do either of these ways:

```
x = replicate(n = ncol, rnorm(5000))
dim(x)
# [1] 5000  100

z = matrix(rnorm(5000 * ncol), ncol = ncol)
dim(z)
# [1] 5000  100
```